# Bing Maps - WebException was unhandled

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am trying to implement bing maps in my project. I just drag and drop the map into Map page.

Now i just navigate from the main page to Map page. When map is loaded I get exception that is

```
WebException was unhandled
```

Error Message is:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at SharpGIS.GZipHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map.LogResponse(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EndGetResponse>b__1(Object sendState)
            at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
            at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4.<FastInvoke>b__3()
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
            at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
            at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

I did not do any other functions. Just Navigate to one page to another page. Please let me know why this error is happen?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What are you dragging and dropping? Is this some premade widget or something? Bing Maps requires writing code and doesn't throw any of the errors you are showing.

Comment: A picture of an exception is useless.  There's a link RIGHT ON THE DIALOG YOU TOOK A PICTURE OF that lets you copy exception details to the clipboard.  You could then do something with it, like, I don't know... paste it in an [edit]?  Or you could paste it in notepad and take a picture of that.

Comment: @rbrundritt.. I don't know how to explain my problem. My XAML is `<Grid x:Name="MapPageUIContainer" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,2,0">
            <my:Map Height="682" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,86,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476"/>          
        </Grid>`. I Just navigate from main page to Map page. When i come to map page, It throws a error.

Comment: Hi @Will.. I just update the question by your instruction.

Comment: +1 for that.  The remote server is returning a 404 from the web request.  So, why are you sending a web request, where is it going, why is it returning a 404, and why isn't there any exception handling for this call?

Comment: Surely i did not send any request to my server.

Comment: Hi @will.. I slaps myself..!! The problem is key. Now I provide the `CredentialsProvider`.. Now it's working Fine..!! Thanks for your reply..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key is the problem. Now only i realize that Bing Map Key is very important for real time project. Now i cleared my problem.

```
<Grid x:Name="MapPageUIContainer" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,2,0">         
            <my:Map Height="688" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,80,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="478" CredentialsProvider="My Key"/> 
        </Grid>
```

Now it is working fine.

Thanks to all Who give support to me to find the problem. Thank you.